# Settlers Of Catan - discarding cards when rolling 7

Tags: catan

If 2 or more players have 8+ cards, do they discard their cards in some "player order" (starting from the one who threw the dice) or is it simultaneous ... is there any specific rule to that situation?

Example:

We played 3 player game.

Player A had 8 cards
Player B had 8 cards
Player C had 0 cards

"A" rolled 7. Player A will steal one card from player B (player C has no cards). Due the card counting player B wants to wait for player A to discard first so he can see the cards and choose better which of his own cards to discard (eliminate the possibility of player A stealing what he is after - maybe discarding 1 ore on purpose if he knows the player A is left with 2 ore and 2 wheat).

So to repeat the question, is there a rule for discarding your hand in some clockwise order or its simultaneous or some third option?

Comment: Amazingly, I can't find any references on the net as to how this should be resolved!  I would be inclined to handle it as a simultaneous action; that is, all players set aside (face down) the cards they'll be discarding, and once that's done, players reveal and discard those piles.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, we did it as simultaneous action but after maybe 30 mins of arguing about it. If someone finds some exact rule about it please post it. Cheers!

Comment: how would a discarder know what another discarder had left in their hand?

Answer (score 17):

The best way to do is simultaneous. While discarding, all the players keep all the cards aside face down. When everyone is done with this then the cards go to bank and are revealed to other players. I have seen this in action on the online version of Settlers of Catan on www.playcatan.com hence I think this is how it should be done.

Comment: If there's no explicit mention of it in the rules, then it has to be simultaneous and face-down as described here. No other way to do it fairly.

Comment: +1 for providing reference in an implementation - I haven't played the online versions in a long time and didn't know how they handle it, which is why I left my note as a comment rather than a proper answer.